# "flutter run" gives me a lot of errors while everything works perfect using "flutter run --no-sound-null-safety"

Tags: flutter

I have been making this app for a while now, and I have always used `flutter run --no-sound-null-safety` to run the app. Everything went well. But now I try to run the project with the command `flutter run` and I get a lot of errors. Errors I wouldn't have gotten when using `flutter run --no-sound-null-safety`.

#### When using `flutter run`

Think of errors like type `type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'bool'`or `The relevant error-causing widget was: Consumer<ConnectivityProvider>` and  `Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'int'`.

Even when I made no changes in the code. How is this possible and what should I do to fix these errors?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: It is waaayy to much to show all the code I've written.

Answer (score 0):

You get these errors because your code is not sound null safe. If you for example initialize

```
bool x = null;
```

you will get an error because null safety tries to avoid errors related to variables that are not initialized. [This](https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide) can help you to make your code null safe.

Comment: Ah okay, but if I make a release build out of it. Does it matter if I use `bool x = null` or can Flutter handle it?

Comment: If you use sound null safety, you also have to do it in the release build.

Comment: Hmm okay, is there an advantage when using the regular `flutter run  -- release` instead of `flutter build apk --release --no-sound-null-safety` ? Or is the command `flutter run --release --no-sound-null-safety`